# Python simple SSL communication

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ssl, server

I want to initiate a simple SSL connection between a client and a server written in python 3, but I am getting errors.

Here is the server code :

```
#/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import ssl

HOST, PORT = '0.0.0.0', 12345

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(10)
client, addr = sock.accept()

# WRAP SOCKET
wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# CONNECT AND PRINT REPLY

print(wrappedSocket.recv(1024))

# CLOSE SOCKET CONNECTION
wrappedSocket.close()
```

And here is the client code :

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import ssl

HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 12345

# CREATE SOCKE
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# WRAP SOCKET
wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# connect and send a message
wrappedSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
wrappedSocket.send(b"Hello")

wrappedSocket.close()
```

And here is the error that I am having on the server side :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "server.py", line 18, in
>
> wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(client, server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 890, in wrap_socket
>       ciphers=ciphers)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 509, in **init**
>       raise ValueError("certfile must be specified for server-side "
>
> ValueError: certfile must be specified for server-side operations

Please, I don't want a complicated SSL connection, I am just looking for the simplest way possible to encrypt the data between the client and the server, just like `ncat` with the `--ssl` option (`ncat --ssl -l -p 12345` from the server side, and `ncat --ssl 127.0.0.1 12345` from the client side).

PS : I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a self-signed certificate using `openssl` and specify in [wrap_socket](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket) the `certfile` attribute and the `keyfile` attribute server side

Generating an RSA public/private-key pair

`openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048`

Generating a self-signed certificate

`openssl req -new -x509 -key private.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095`

Answer (score 0):

Using SSL as the security protocol will require you to either create or purchase SSL certificates since that is a required part of the handshake.

From [RFC 6101](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101#section-5.6.2)

> 5.6.2.  Server Certificate
>
> If the server is to be authenticated (which is generally the case),
> the server sends its certificate immediately following the server hello message. The certificate type must be appropriate for the
> selected cipher suite's key exchange algorithm, and is generally an      X.509.v3 certificate

Comment: Is there any other simple way to encrypt the data between two peers ??

Answer (score 0):

Pass your certfile to the wrapper:

```
 from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
 import ssl
 httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
 httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, 
                 certfile='/tmp/tcert_key.pem', server_side=True)
 httpd.serve_forever()
```

Then you have to enter your passphrase for your selfsigned secured private key. The integrated key file (certfile) can be generated with cat or type in the shell:

type tkey.pem tcert.pem > tcert_key.pem

is equivalent of:

$ cat file1 file2 > file3

It is possible to remove the passphrase of the private key file for the secured server side case. OpenSSL provides utils to do that. For example:

```
 openssl pkey -in yourkey-with-pass.pem -out yourkey-without-pass.pem
```